# Managing Large Databases of Images

Tags: mysql

I started working on a side project during the night. And it requires me to use large amounts of images, similar to Instagram, what do you recommend using as a database for this?

Should I upload the file to a path and referenced it from the database? Or should I use another type of database and upload the pictures there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Should I upload the file to a path and referenced it from the database" - yes. Storing objects in mysql like that as a blob is bad practice. Put them in a directory somewhere and reference the path from your database of choice.. mysql is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a good idea to store image directly in DB. DB size will increase. DB Hit will increase. So better store image as file in server and store the reference path in DB.

For Detailed Info :- [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)